# Nodejs app running on localhost:3000 is not accessible on Linux server

Tags: node.js, centos

I want to deploy my web app on cloud server, the OS is Centos 7, I got a static IP address like "34.80.XXX.XX", if I set my web app running on port 80, and I can see the page when I enter "34.80.XXX.XX:80".

But I if I running on port 3000, and enter "34.80.XXX.XX:3000", it not working.

I have tried to stop my firewall:

```
# systemctl stop firewalld
```

And use the command below to check there is no other program running on port 3000

```
# netstat -tnlp
```

Here is the code in app.js

```
const Koa = require('koa')
const json = require('koa-json')

const app = new Koa()
const PORT = 3000

// make JSON Prettier middleware
app.use(json())

// Simple middleware example
app.use(async ctx => {
    ctx.body = {msg: 'Hello World'}
})

app.listen(PORT)
console.log(`server run at http://localhost:${PORT}`)
```

I use pm2 to run it in background

```
[root@instance-1 01-hello]# pm2 start app.js -n hello
[PM2] Starting /home/xing/01-hello/app.js in fork_mode (1 instance)
[PM2] Done.
┌─────┬──────────┬─────────────┬─────────┬─────────┬──────────┬────────┬──────┬───────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ id  │ name     │ namespace   │ version │ mode    │ pid      │ uptime │ ↺    │ status    │ cpu      │ mem      │ user     │ watching │  
├─────┼──────────┼─────────────┼─────────┼─────────┼──────────┼────────┼──────┼───────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┤  
│ 0   │ hello    │ default     │ N/A     │ fork    │ 3835     │ 0s     │ 0    │ online    │ 0%       │ 12.6mb   │ root     │ disabled │  
└─────┴──────────┴─────────────┴─────────┴─────────┴──────────┴────────┴──────┴───────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┘
```

And I enter the command `netstat -tnlp` to check app.js is running on port 3000

```
[root@instance-1 01-hello]# netstat -tnlp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      15958/sshd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1184/master
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2421/mongod
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      15958/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::3000                 :::*                    LISTEN      3835/node /home/xin
tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN      1184/master
```

I have stuck on this point for long time, is there any good solution

Comment: when you run the nodejs app, do you see the port 3000 is listen on your `netstat -tnlp` command?

Comment: Yes, I use pm2 to run the app.js and, enter `netstat -tnlp` command to check app.js is listen on port 3000

Comment: You can use this [tool](https://canyouseeme.org/) to verify from external if the port 3000 is open. My guess is your hosting service limits access to only some ports for security reasons.

Comment: Hey, I find the solution. I am using google cloud server, and I should create the the firewall rules and open port 3000.